# List of kufr and shirk acts?

Tags: shirk, apostasy

Is there a list of disbeliever and shirk acts, and do you have to say the Shahada again, if you do them?  Or is there a website which lists them? In a article?

Comment: I am not going to list anything as your question demand, but subjective answer will be very useful to relate things, what is shirk and what is not.The problem is with objective answer things can change over region,situation,ages...etc. This link will describe your Question [What is Shirk in Islam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eppNI_EnPso)

Comment: Here is [a book chapter](http://www.al-islam.org/greater-sins-volume-1-ayatullah-sayyid-abd-al-husayn-dastghayb-shirazi/first-greater-sin-shirk) listing and explaining in detail deeds that amount to shirk and deeds that don't. This is written by a Shiite scholar however Shiism and Sunnism almost totally agree on fundamentals of belief.

Comment: Study An- Nawqid ul Islam (nullifiers of Islam) - you'll find your answer

Answer (score 1):

**Shirk** is the violation of Tawheed (oneness and Uniqueness of Allah swt.)

- Shirk in al-Rububiyah - Believing that there is another that shares
  in the Lordship of Allah swt

  - Associating partners
  - Negating the Lordship of Allah swt
- Shirk in al-Asma was Sifat

  - Humanizing Allah swt
  - Deifying Human beings
- Shirk in al-Ibadah - Directing worship to other than Allah swt

  - Taghut (worshiping something along with Allah swt or instead of Allah swt).
    This is Major Shirk or Ash-shirk Al-Akbar
  - ar-Riya (showing off) ie. Doing acts of Ibadah not for the sake Allah swt but for the sake of others. This is minor shirk or Ash-shirk al-Asghar

Many things, including, neglecting salat can make you **kafir**.

> “Between a man and shirk and kufr there stands his neglect of the
>   prayer.” (Narrated by Muslim in *Kitaab al-Imaan* from Jaabir ibn
>   ‘Abd-Allaah from the Prophet saw).

The most important act of kufr being denying Allah and his Prophet salah allahu alayhi wa salam.

As far as coming back to Islam after shirk or kufr if you return to salat and ask for forgiveness this should be sufficient if Allah swt wills. As Allah swt says:

> فَإِن تَابُواْ وَأَقَامُواْ ٱلصَّلَوٰةَ وَءَاتَوُاْ ٱلزَّڪَوٰةَ
>   فَإِخۡوَٲنُكُمۡ فِى ٱلدِّينِ‌ۗ وَنُفَصِّلُ ٱلۡأَيَـٰتِ لِقَوۡمٍ۬
>   يَعۡلَمُونَ
>
> But if they repent and establish worship and pay the poor-due, then
>   are they your brethren in religion. We detail Our revelations for a
>   people who have knowledge.
>
> (al-Tawbah 9:11)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I formatted your answer for better readability. As for the deeds leading to Kufr, the most important thing is to stop believing in Allah and His Prophet. You might want to consider adding that to your answer.